# JSON deserialization doesn't want to fit in model

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I'm consuming a service that returns this JSON, when mapping in the model only takes me the first object but the `sms` field with the other objects is empty.

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "cliente": "999999",
  "lote_id": "99999999999999",
  "fecha_recepcion": "2019-04-29 12:31:35",
  "resultado": 0,
  "resultado_t": null,
  "sms_procesados": 2,
  "referecia": "Referencia Prueba",
  "ip": "999.999.99.9",
  "sms": {
    "1": {
      "id": "9999999",
      "numero": "999999999",
      "sms": "tests",
      "fecha_envio": "2019-04-29 12:31:35",
      "ind_area_nom": "cell",
      "precio_sms": "9.00000",
      "resultado_t": "",
      "resultado": "0"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "8888888",
      "numero": "9999998888",
      "sms": "test",
      "fecha_envio": "2019-04-29 12:31:35",
      "ind_area_nom": "Celular",
      "precio_sms": "9.00000",
      "resultado_t": "",
      "resultado": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my model:

```
public class ResultadoSms
{
    public string cliente { get; set; }
    public Int64 lote_id { get; set; }
    public string fecha_recepcion { get; set; }
    public Int64 resultado { get; set; }
    public object resultado_t { get; set; }
    public Int64 sms_procesados { get; set; }
    public string referecia { get; set; }
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public Sms sms { get; set; }
}

public class Sms 
{       
    public CuerpoSms CuerpoSms { get; set; }
}

public class CuerpoSms
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string numero { get; set; }
    public string sms { get; set; }
    public string fecha_envio { get; set; }
    public string ind_area_nom { get; set; }
    public string precio_sms { get; set; }
    public string resultado_t { get; set; }
    public string resultado { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to convert the `sms` field into a list but it's still empty. I don't understand what the problem is or how I could deserialize the object in another easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is not accounting for the `1`, `2`, etc. keys inside the `sms` object in the JSON.  You need to use a `Dictionary<string, CuerpoSms>` to handle that.

Change this line:

```
public Sms sms { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
public Dictionary<string, CuerpoSms> sms { get; set; }
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1XiwSF

Comment: thank you friend, this is what I did not understand, because in the field come N objects and could not create a class for each one, now its working!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The `sms` in the returned JSON is an object with **2 properties**, both having the same structure as your `CuerpoSms`.

To have them automatically serialized in your C# code, you would need to:

```
public class Sms 
{       
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public CuerpoSms CuerpoSms1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2")]
    public CuerpoSms CuerpoSms2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I failed to specify that in the sms field is filled with N objects and could not create a class for each one